# Anyone know which image uploader facebook uses?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, image, file-upload

Want to add a nice multiple image upload feature to a site so I figured use one that most people already know.  This is a .Net MVC App

Anyone know what Facebook uses?

If not, then does anyone know of one that is similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it will work perfectly and seems pretty close to FB:

http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/OnlineDemo.aspx#BasicDemo

Comment: I think this is actually the one they use, check this demo - looks exact: http://demo.aurigma.com/ImageUploader6/OptimizedUpload/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Their own?  I'm pretty sure when get to facebook like scale everything becomes modified and customized so suit your needs.